# VSTO Call ThisAddIn Method from Ribbon Class

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a simple Problem. I have a litte Outlook AddIn. Now I want to add a Ribbon to it, for manually executing a Method.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace;
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox;
    Outlook.Items items;
    Outlook.MAPIFolder destinationFolder = null;
    Outlook.MAPIFolder rootFolder = null;
    //Outlook.Folders rootFolderFolders = null;
    Outlook.Store store = null;



    protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        return new MyRibbon();
    }



    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        items = inbox.Items;
        items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Items_ItemAdd);

    }

       public void RibbonAction()
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Action Found Class");
            Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer = null;
            currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();


        }
```

And MyRibbon.cs

```
public class MyRibbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
    {
        private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

        public MyRibbon()
        {
        }

        public void OnTextButton(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
                        
thisAddIn.RibbonAction();

        }
```

I want to iterate through the the selected Items in the Outlook explorer. It seems I can not do this in MyRibbon, so I want to implement the Method in thisAddIn. But Visual Studio let me not do this.

Comment: What do you mean "Visual Studio let me not do this"? Can you post the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you don't use the function `RibbonAction()` in the class `ThisAddIn`, delete it here and insert the function directly in the class `MyRibbon`.

To get the `ActiveExplorer` somewhere else as in `ThisAddIn` class you can use the following code:

```cs
Outlook.Explorer activeExplorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
```